# Should I always do $em->clear(); in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have seen some stuff online about the need to use `$em->clear();` in order to prevent memory leaks. I don't know anything about memory leaks.

In the official docs, I see `$em->clear();` isn't used much. Should I make it a practice to do this on each request that uses the entity manager?

Comment: In php, each request is independent and starts with it's own fresh pool of memory.  No need to worry about memory leaks between requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. `$em->clear();` will detach all entities that are currently managed by this EntityManager. This will only be useful when running batch-scripts with huge amounts of data.

`$em->flush();` will be most likely sufficient, unless you are starting to struggle with memory limits.

Comment: @Travis Please mark this as an answer if you find the explanation satisfying.